# How flv downloader browser extentions work?

Tags: download, flash, browser-addons

I am wondering how these kind of applications produce an obfuscated url to make you able to download the video in mp4 ? And these produced urls can be directly streamed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Almost all video services have alternative hidden URL for each video where you can download it directly.   That extensions know how to "build" that URL from your video link.

**Long answer:**

Usually it's not so hard to find that URLs and Chrome's F12, Ctrl+U or Maxthon's built-in downloader do the work. And usually such URLs have ID-like parameter, so if you change it with another video ID, you can download that video too.
The work is harder if they have hash-like parameters, then you must find out how that hashes are added. But most services (especially little ones) use easy algorithms like Base64, add there some date-time-timeout and some ID. In this case your work is easy.

(P.S. I've just tried and it took me about 5 minutes with Chrome F12 to find direct URL for DailyMotion.)

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that with F12 and couldn't achieve. I'll retry.

Comment: @ybaylav Which site have you tried?

Comment: www.alkislarlayasiyorum.com

Comment: Easy. Press Ctrl+U, then press Ctrl+F and type there ".mp4" (without "). I've just found the direct URL of first video in your site.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking about to write a script to send me these urls. Because in the country that I'm working in, most of these kind of sites are banned. But if you get the url, you can watch whatever video you want. And ofcourse without any bandwidth limitation due to proxy or VPN servers.

Comment: Is that a turkish site? As I know a lot of sites are banned in Turkey. In that case [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) can help you too.

Comment: Yeah it's a Turkish site, but I'm in Saudi Arabia. Comparing to Turkey, this is direct definition of the hell.